# Is it possible to force a relationship to be one-to-one instead of one-to-many? if not, then what?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, database-design, inner-join

I have a database assignment due very soon and I am wasting a lot of time on the wrong things.

To keep it simple, I have a table called Character that draws info from many tables, one of them being Inventory. Both Character and Inventory have a field called inventory_ID which is the PK in the Inventory Table.

```
SELECT gold, char_name
FROM Inventory, Character
```

I tried to write a query to get the gold from every character, so instead of, for example:

```
character 1 : 200 gold
character 2 : 500 gold
```

it shows:

```
character 1 : 200 gold
character 1 : 500 gold
character 2 : 200 gold
character 2 : 500 gold
```

When making the relationships, I noticed that I cannot manually change the type. Most of the time, this is fine, but for this one, I think the problem is that Inventory has a one-to-many relationship with Character, thus making it so every character has one of every Inventory(?).

I've been bashing my head in this for quite a while and time is running out, I didn't want to resort to asking for help, but I see no other option.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code generates a cartesian products of both tables. Instead, you need to `join`, using common column `inventory_id` to relate the rows of the two tables:

```
select i.gold, c.char_name
from inventory as i
inner join character as c on c.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
```

If a `character` may have more than one match in `inventory`, aggregation might be necessary:

```
select sum(i.gold) as gold, c.char_name
from inventory as i
inner join character as c on c.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
group by c.char_name
```

However this is not what your question suggests. The first query should do what you want.

Comment: That does really fix my issue with the query, but does it solve the problem? Wouldn't it make more sense for the relationship to be one-to-one, since one character should have one inventory and each inventory should belong to only one character?

Still, thanks a lot tho for the instant response, appreciate it!

Comment: @MagorTuga: well, if you do have a 1-1 relationship, then normalization principles would advocate to merge the two tables together.

Comment: So, I assume the issue is with the requirement for the tables to be separate and not the way I'm doing it, right?

Should I trust Access to accurately know what the correct relationship is?

Comment: @MagorTuga: well, given your current design, you were not doing it right. My answer explains why, and how to do. Fixing the schema itself would be good too, although that's a different concern.

Answer (score 0):

To supplement @GMB answer, you can set the `Indexed` to `Yes(No Duplicates)` for the `Inventory_Id` field in the `Characters` table. This will prevent adding duplicate Inventory_Id on a table level in MS Access. This will give you the 1-1 relationship.

[image]